# Como selecionar elemento dentro de outro com CSS?

Tags: css

Tenho um tema WordPress que, ao ser executado, gera o seguinte código:

```
<div class="wpb_wrapper">
  <article class="icon-box11">
    <i class="fa-shield" style=" font-size:3em; color:#00ced1;"></i>
    <h4>ANOS DE GARANTIA</h4>
    <p>Todos os produtos instalados possuem 5 anos de garantia contra defeitos de fabricação.<br></p>
  </article>
</div>
```

Tendo por base a classe `icon-box11`, como criar um código CSS que altere os elementos `h4` e `p`?

Abraços.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segue um exemplo:

```css
.icon-box11 h4{
  color:red;
}

.icon-box11 p{
  color:blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="wpb_wrapper">
<h4>H4 fora do icon-box11</h4>
<p>P fora do icon-box11</p>
  <article class="icon-box11">
    <i class="fa-shield" style=" font-size:3em; color:#00ced1;"></i>
    <h4>ANOS DE GARANTIA</h4>
    <p>Todos os produtos instalados possuem 5 anos de garantia contra defeitos de fabricação.<br></p>
  </article>
</div>
```

Comment: sua resposta está correta, mas só pra eu entender melhor, caso eu quisesse acessar essas mesmas tags, mas vindo da classe wpb_wrapper, como eu faria?

Comment: Vc muda o seletor para ela e todos os elementos declarados dentro, receberão o estilo.

Answer (score 2):

voce trata as childs com elementos concatenados na msm linha:

```
 .icon-box11 h4{
  }
```

e

```
.icon-box11 p{
 }
```

Desta forma a regra se aplicará apenas às H4 e p filhas da sua classe icon-box11